# How to add prefix to headings in OpenOffice Writer?

Tags: openoffice-writer

I've recently decided to never, ever use Microsoft Word ever again. I have started into OpenOffice Writer today and I'm trying to get my template document set up. For my project I need to have "Section 1. - " added to the beginning of each Heading 1. I could do this in Word, I'm hoping it's possible in Writer too.

To be clear, I'm trying to accomplish this:

Section 1. - Heading 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an "options" tab within the Numbering Style window, it allows you to add something "before" or "after" each numbering level.

[image: Screenshot]